# copying a range n number of times where n is specified in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

Firstly i am a complete novice in VBA.
I am trying to copy a range in column A and B(dynamic rows) "n" number of times where I specify the value of n in cell "c2" to another sheet in the same workbook.

```
Column A   Column B

DDDDDD      d345g
THFGJJ      th567
JKHNGF      thgf4
UJHG67      uj768
tkm78y      y7865
```

here is what i tried but it is giving me a break error.

```
Sub rangecopy()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rangeini As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    rangeini = Sheets("sheet1").[a10000].End(xlUp).Row+1 //range of data to copy
    n = Sheets("sheet1").range("c2")//number of times to be copied
    For i = 1 To n

        rangeini.Copy
        Sheets("sheet2").range("A2").PasteSpecial//data to be pasted here

    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

I am in a fix and need it asap. Any help is really appreciated.

Please write a simple code so a novice can understand and learn from that.

Comment: What do you mean by `Break Error`?

Comment: Make sure n doesn't exceed the size limit of integers since you have declared  i as an integer that may be causing a problem

Comment: My interpretation of your `Break Error` (I could be wrong though) Replace `//` by `'`

Comment: `rangeini` is defined as Long - if you want top copy it then it needs to be defined as a Range

Answer (score 1):

This just does a simple copy/paste

```
Sub rangecopy()

    Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
    Dim intHowmany As Integer


    n = Sheets("sheet1").Range("c2") 'number of times to be copied

    Range("a2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, (Selection.Offset(0, 1))).Select

    Selection.Copy

    intHowmany = Selection.Rows.Count

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Select
    Range("a2").Select


    For i = 1 To n

        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(intHowmany, 0).Select


    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub rangecopy() 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Dim rangeini As range  
    Dim i As Integer, n as integer
    Set rangeini = Sheets("sheet1").range("a2").resize(Sheets("sheet1").[a2].End(xlDown).Row - 1, 2) 'range of data to copy 
    n = Sheets("sheet1").range("c2") 'number of times to be copied

    Sheets("sheet2").[a2] = rangeini 'paste the first one in "a2"
    For i = 2 To n

        Sheets("sheet2").[a1].Offset(Sheets("sheet2").[a2].End(xlDown).row) = rangeini  'data to be pasted at the end 

    Next i 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```